# How to create complex join between three tables using Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have three tables (I'll list only important fields):

**Format**

- id
- template_id
- parameterisation_id

**Param**

- name
- value
- parameterisation_id

**ParamDict**

- name
- template_id

I need to map params into formats into one-to-many association, but they do not have direct connection and needed to be joined through ParamDict table.

I currently did it with @JoinTable like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "123", name = "format")
public class Format implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;
private String template_id;
private String parameterisation_id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "paramDict", schema = "123",
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "template_id", referencedColumnName = 
"template_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)},
inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "param_name", referencedColumnName = 
"param_name",insertable = false,updatable = false)})
private Set<Param> params = new HashSet<>()
}
```

And in sql it looks like this

```
Select * from
Format f
left join ParamDict pd on f.template_id = pd.template_id
left join Param p on p.name = pd.name;
```

But now i need to add another condition in Param join:

```
 Select * from
    Format f
    left join ParamDict pd on f.template_id = pd.template_id
    left join Param p on (p.name = pd.name and p.parameterisation_id = f.parameterisation_id);
```

I tried to add where clause into @Query annotation in my Repository:

```
public interface FormatRepository extends Repository<Format, String> {
    @Query("select n from format f "
            + "left join fetch f.params p "
            + "where f.parameterisation_id in (?1) "
            + "and f.parameterisation_id = p.parameterisation_id"
    )
    Set<Format> findBypParameterisationIdIn(List<String> ids);
}
```

And it created right sql query, but Hibernate does not count that condition (f.parameterisation_id = p.parameterisation_id) when mapping query results into class objects, and i get wrong results in Param set (there are items in the **params** set, that does not have the same parameterisation_id as **Format**).
How can i do it via Hibernate mapping?

Comment: What does that mean "Hibernate does not count that condition..."? Please write more clearly what it is that doesn't work vs. what you expect.

Comment: If i use that formation, there are items in the params set, that does not have the same parameterisation_id as Format, albeit having that condition in the @ Query. I think that Hibernate only uses @ JoinTable conditions of join, when packing objects into sets.